# I am having trouble importing and using the classes in the amazon sdk? It should be simple, but have been trying to compile for the past few hours.

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't know why this is so difficult, I am trying to use amazon sdk to upload photos. I'm just following the swift instructions here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios

As well as trying out these tutorials: http://sledgedev.com/aws-s3-image-upload-using-aws-sdk-for-ios-v2/, http://shrikar.com/ios-app-development-upload-images-to-aws-s3/

However, none of them are working, since I can't compile. I keep getting unresolved identifier warnings every time an aws class is called, like AWSDynamoDB.

I have a bridging file set up, and its pointed correctly, as the compiler didn't catch any errors with the file path, but the problem still exists. What else could I possibly be doing wrong? Please help, I am seeking advice, I am going crazy here.

```
#ifndef ObjectiveC_Bridging_Header_h
#define ObjectiveC_Bridging_Header_h

#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>
#import <AWSSQS/AWSSQS.h>
#import <AWSSNS/AWSSNS.h>
#import <AWSCognito/AWSCognito.h>

#endif /* ObjectiveC_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Comment: please  provide more detailed about the compile issue. What kind of error occurred while compiling? Which line causes the error? you mentioned the  "unresolved identifier warnings" but since it is a warning, it shouldn't prevent you from compile the project.